# NGRX and the tsconfig strict flag

Tags: typescript, ngrx, typechecking, strict

Perusing the ngrxplatform repo [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform), I was pleased to see that the strict flag is enabled in the tsconfig.json file.  This ensures that the strict typechecking is enforced during the compile.

However, looking at the sample applications listed on the Ngrx website [here](https://ngrx.io/resources), none of these sample applications make use of the strict flag (a few apps have one or two flags enabled, but most have no flags enabled).

In fact I couldn't find a single ngrx application on github that uses the strict flag (if you know of one please post the link).

I'm worried I'm missing something here.  Is there a reason NOT to use the strict flag for an enterprise level production application?  If not, why not a good example of its use?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  Should have done a bit more digging.  All three example apps in the ngrx platfrom repo's projects folder have the strict flag enabled:

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects